# Each time when I start new Android studio project this error occurred

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Each time when I start a new project this error occurred
Please, anyone, help me......
is there something missing from the android studio

[image]

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.shareque.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
E:\myapps\BetaApps\Digitalworldapp\app\src\main\res\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(15, 49) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(16, 45) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(17, 47) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(18, 43) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' with value 'parent').
E:\myapps\BetaApps\Digitalworldapp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(15, 49) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(16, 45) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(17, 47) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(18, 43) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' with value 'parent').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 7.672 secs
>   Information:9 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Have you included the dependency for the ConstraintLayout?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you by change install using an already existing SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solve after changing constraint-layout dependency from

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
```

in app level Gradle file

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Android Studio and used an existing - and outdated - Android SDK installation (like I did recently), you may have to install the new ConstraintLayout library from the Support Repository. Afterwards you may need to adjust the used dependency in the app's build.gradle file (like you did).

From then on, when you start a new project using Android Studio, the right dependency will be included in the build.gradle.

[image: Install ConstraintLayout for Android]